# Errors were encountered while processing: /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VaNlgQ/10-libnvidia-gl-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management

I am trying to install an Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 20.04. When I run this command

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

I get an error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VaNlgQ/10-libnvidia-gl-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why are trying to install an old and obsoleted driver?

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps:

1. Select **Show applications** from gnome UI.
2. Type 'software' and select **Software and Updates**
3. Find **Additional drivers** tab and select it.
4. Open Terminal, type `lscpi -v` and validate your version of Nvidia and then check against
   https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/
5. Select your appropriate propriety server Nvidia Driver.

Hope your driver/hardware is on the list.